# PS Plus Monthly Games Already Owned

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I live in Germany and I'm a PS Plus user since last October. I've been really enjoying the monthly free games since it pushes you to go out of your comfort zone with video games and try excellent titles that you would never buy.

One of the first games I bought when I got my PS4 was Detroit Become Human. I decided to sell it later on, and quit playing it completely, however, I decided it to keep it in my physical library.

And here comes July, and Detroit Become Human is going to be one of the two free games for this month.

What happens if you already own a title that is in the monthly free games? Is it possible in any way for title owners to change the games they get? They said it's gonna be digital deluxe edition and I have the standard edition, can I at least have the benefits of the digital deluxe edition? Is the whole thing completely worthless?

Comment: "Is it possible in any way for title owners to change the games they get?" - No, absolutely not. Although I feel like you just get the option to download the free game just like everyone else.

Answer (score 5):

If you already have any of the free games then its tough luck. You do not get anything extra. Its worth noting though that the version you actually purchased will work whether you have an active plus subscription or not where as the free copy will only work while you have an active subscription.

Whether you can get the extra content or not will depend on how / if they have split the items that make up the deluxe edition.

It looks like you will at least get Heavy Rain as part of the deluxe edition of if you do not own it.

Comment: I don't own it but I already finished it back in the day when I had my PS3, I don't think I will play it again if the graphics aren't remastered. Too bad Sony is doing this, I think if they allow the users to choose only 2 from 5 possible games it would be much more effective and more people will be encouraged to subscribe. I just hope this happens some day.

Comment: I think its a complained that has been well heard, especially with them dropping PS3 and Vita games this year. Its been the worst year for me so far with regards to already having most of the games.